# How to make the positions of buttons in navbar fixed even when the screen size changes in Dash-plotly with python

Tags: python, html, plotly, plotly-dash, dash-bootstrap-components

I am trying to keep the position of the buttons fixed in the Nanbar of my Dash app even when we zoom in the browser or if the screen size changes. I used dash bootstrap components to make the layout but the buttons disorient when I zoom in or if I use a smaller display. I am new to this so any help would be appreciated.

At 100% zoom
[image: The layout I want to fix the navbar]

At 110% zoom
[image: buttons disoriented]

this is my code

```
import random
import time
import webbrowser
from collections import deque

import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input

BS = "https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css"
app = dash.Dash('vehicle-data', external_stylesheets=[BS])

button_group = html.Div(
    [
        dbc.NavbarBrand(dcc.Link(
            dbc.Button(children='HOME',
                       style={
                           'display': 'inline-block',
                           'align': 'center',
                           'color': 'white', 'marginLeft': '100px',
                           'fontSize': '15px ',
                           'backgroundColor': '#101820',
                           'width': '150px',
                           'height': '50px',
                           'marginRight': '100px'
                       }, className='lg'),

            href='http://127.0.0.1:5050/', refresh=True), className='lg'),

        dbc.NavbarBrand(dcc.Link(
            dbc.Button(children='OVERVIEW',
                       style={'color': 'white',
                              'backgroundColor': '#101820',
                              'marginLeft': '10px',
                              'fontSize': '15px ',
                              'width': '150px',
                              'marginRight': '100px',
                              'height': '50px'
                              }),
            href='/pages/overview', refresh=True)),
        dbc.NavbarBrand(dcc.Link(
            dbc.Button(children='GRAPH',
                       style={'color': 'white',
                              'backgroundColor': '#101820',
                              'fontSize': '15px ',
                              'marginLeft': '10px',
                              'marginRight': '100px',
                              'width': '150px',
                              'height': '50px'
                              }),
            href='/pages/graph_page', refresh=True)),
        dbc.NavbarBrand(dcc.Link(
            dbc.Button(children='CONSOLE',
                       style={'color': 'white',
                              'backgroundColor': '#101820',
                              'fontSize': '15px ',
                              'marginLeft': '10px',
                              'marginRight': '100px',
                              'width': '150px',
                              'height': '50px'
                              }),
            href='/log_stream', refresh=True)),
        dbc.NavbarBrand(dcc.Link(
            dbc.Button(children='DIAGNOSTIC',
                       style={'color': 'white',
                              'backgroundColor': '#101820',
                              'marginLeft': '2px',
                              'fontSize': '15px ',
                              'width': '170px',
                              'marginRight': '100px',
                              'height': '50px'
                              }),
            href='/pages/diag', refresh=True))
    ],

)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        dbc.Row(
            [
                dbc.Col([button_group]),
            ],
            style={
                'textAlign': 'center',
                'position': 'sticky',
                'backgroundColor': '#101820',
                'display': 'flex',
                'marginRight': '0px',
            },
        ),
        dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),
        html.Div(id='page-content', children=[])
    ]),
])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    webbrowser.open('http://127.0.0.1:8050/')
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

[image: latest]

Comment: What behavior should the buttons have when resizing the window or when zooming?

Comment: I was trying to make them stick to the same line (aligned in one line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add `brand="Fixed Navbar"` to your code just like shown below:

```
nav = dbc.NavbarSimple(
    children=[
        dbc.NavItem(dbc.NavLink("Page 1", href="#")),
        dbc.DropdownMenu(
            children=[
                dbc.DropdownMenuItem("More pages", header=True),
                dbc.DropdownMenuItem("Page 2", href="#"),
                dbc.DropdownMenuItem("Page 3", href="#"),
            ],
            nav=True,
            in_navbar=True,
            label="More",
        ),
    ],
    brand="Fixed Navbar",
    brand_href="#",
    color="lightgreen",
    dark=True,
)
```

now above assigned `nav` can be added to UI by:

```
app.layout = html.Div(children=[

    nav,
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Also,
make sure to add `import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc` to your code.

Answer (score 2):

```
import random
import time
import webbrowser
from collections import deque

import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input

BS = "https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css"
app = dash.Dash('vehicle-data', external_stylesheets=[BS])

button_group = html.Div(
    [
        dbc.NavbarBrand(dcc.Link(
            dbc.Button(children='HOME',
                       style={
                           'display': 'inline-block',
                           'align': 'center',
                           'color': 'white', 'marginLeft': '100px',
                           'fontSize': '15px ',
                           'backgroundColor': '#101820',
                           'width': '150px',
                           'height': '50px',
                           'marginRight': '100px'
                       }, className='lg'),

            href='http://127.0.0.1:5050/', refresh=True), className='lg'),

        dbc.NavbarBrand(dcc.Link(
            dbc.Button(children='OVERVIEW',
                       style={'color': 'white',
                              'backgroundColor': '#101820',
                              'marginLeft': '10px',
                              'fontSize': '15px ',
                              'width': '150px',
                              'marginRight': '100px',
                              'height': '50px'
                              }),
            href='/pages/overview', refresh=True)),
        dbc.NavbarBrand(dcc.Link(
            dbc.Button(children='GRAPH',
                       style={'color': 'white',
                              'backgroundColor': '#101820',
                              'fontSize': '15px ',
                              'marginLeft': '10px',
                              'marginRight': '100px',
                              'width': '150px',
                              'height': '50px'
                              }),
            href='/pages/graph_page', refresh=True)),
        dbc.NavbarBrand(dcc.Link(
            dbc.Button(children='CONSOLE',
                       style={'color': 'white',
                              'backgroundColor': '#101820',
                              'fontSize': '15px ',
                              'marginLeft': '10px',
                              'marginRight': '100px',
                              'width': '150px',
                              'height': '50px'
                              }),
            href='/log_stream', refresh=True)),
        dbc.NavbarBrand(dcc.Link(
            dbc.Button(children='DIAGNOSTIC',
                       style={'color': 'white',
                              'backgroundColor': '#101820',
                              'marginLeft': '2px',
                              'fontSize': '15px ',
                              'width': '170px',
                              'marginRight': '100px',
                              'height': '50px'
                              }),
            href='/pages/diag', refresh=True))
    ],

)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        dbc.Row(
            [
                dbc.Col([button_group]),
            ],
            style={
                'textAlign': 'center',
                'position': 'sticky',
                'backgroundColor': '#101820',
                'display': 'flex',
                'marginRight': '0px',
                'maxWidth':'1500px',
                'width':'1500px'
            },
        ),
        dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),
        html.Div(id='page-content', children=[])
    ]),
])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    webbrowser.open('http://127.0.0.1:8050/')
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the contents of the block from being wrapped to another line, you need to add the `white-space: nowrap;` to this block CSS style.

So, for Dash it is `'whiteSpace': 'nowrap'`:

```py
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        dbc.Row(
            [
                dbc.Col(
                    [button_group],
                    style={'whiteSpace': 'nowrap'}
                ),
            ],
            style={
                'textAlign': 'center',
                'position': 'sticky',
                'backgroundColor': '#101820',
                'display': 'flex',
                'marginRight': '0px',
            },
        ),
        dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),
        html.Div(id='page-content', children=[])
    ]),
])
```

The only way to display the navigation bar correctly when the zoom changes, which I know is a fixed width layout.

This is a sample code with a little refactoring. The style of the buttons has been moved to `nav_btn_style`, unnecessary nested elements have been removed.

```py
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

# BS = "https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css"
app = dash.Dash('vehicle-data', external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

# style for navigation buttons
nav_btn_style = {
    'align': 'center',
    'color': 'white', 
    'backgroundColor': '#101820',
    'fontSize': '1rem',
    'width': '10rem',
    'height': '3.2rem',
    'margin': '0rem 1rem',
}

button_group = dbc.Nav(
    [
        dbc.NavItem(dcc.Link(
            dbc.Button(
                children='HOME',
                style=nav_btn_style,
                ),
            href='/',
            refresh=True),
            ),
        dbc.NavItem(dcc.Link(
            dbc.Button(
                children='OVERVIEW',
                style=nav_btn_style,
                ),
            href='/pages/overview',
            refresh=True),
            ),
        dbc.NavItem(dcc.Link(
            dbc.Button(
                children='GRAPH',
                style=nav_btn_style,
                ),
            href='/pages/graph_page',
            refresh=True),
            ),
        dbc.NavItem(dcc.Link(
            dbc.Button(
                children='CONSOLE',
                style=nav_btn_style
                ),
            href='/log_stream',
            refresh=True),
            ),
        dbc.NavItem(dcc.Link(
            dbc.Button(
                children='DIAGNOSTIC',
                style=nav_btn_style,
                ),
            href='/pages/diag',
            refresh=True),
            )
    ],
    horizontal='around',
    style={
        'flexWrap': 'nowrap',  # no wrap buttons 
        'padding': '0.5rem 3rem',
        'border': '3px dotted crimson',  # nav bar border
        'position': 'sticky',
        'backgroundColor': '#101820',
        }
)

app.layout = html.Div([
    button_group,
    dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),
    html.Div(
        id='page-content', children=['TEST'],
        style={
            'height': '20rem',
            'border': '3px dotted royalblue',
            'display': 'flex',
            'justifyContent': 'center',
            'alignItems': 'center'
            }
        ),
    ],
    style={'margin': '0px auto', 'width': '80rem'}  # fixed width for outer div
)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    webbrowser.open('http://127.0.0.1:8050/')
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

and how it look

[image: resulting page]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but with this code, if I zoom in the buttons are going out of the navbar. I have added the picture.

Comment: @rohith santosh A couple of questions. 1. The style sheet used breaks the arrangement of elements in the navigation bar. Is it necessary to use this particular stylesheet? 2. Do you need to use NavbarBrand instead of NavItem?

Comment: The stylesheet can be `external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP]
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets, suppress_callback_exceptions=True)` we can change the NavbarBrand to NavItem

Comment: supplemented my answer

Comment: Thanks again, can we not make the width just according to the size of the screen?